# How can I add sql server express 2008 version into prerequisites in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, setup-deployment

I have visual studio 2012 (professional edition) installed in my computer.I have created windows application with sql database.I want to deploy windows application using clickonce method of deployment.It should include Sql Server 2008 Express in setup file.But I can't find Sql Server 2008 Express in my prerequisite list.I can only find sql server 2012 express version.how can I add Sql Server 2008 Express option inside my prerequisite list.I want to specifically use the 2008 version rather than 2012 version.

Comment: Maybe too late but look at this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manisblog/2008/12/22/how-to-deploy-sql-server-2008-express-as-a-prerequisite-with-clickonce/

Comment: Thanks..will look into it